# WebView for mac app in "visual studio for mac"

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac, visual-studio-mac

I make the app for mac.
The IDE which I use is the "Visual studio for MAC".
I need to use the component, which can display web pages in this app, but
"Visual studio for MAC" have no elements at the tool panel such as webView.
How can add component, which can display web pages and execute the JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you do follow Xamarin's guide,

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/#Introduction_to_Xcode_and_Interface_Builder

Then you should know that in Interface Builder you can add WebKit View from the Object Library.